# c# pause within catch statement not working

Tags: c#

I have a `try/catch` block and within catch am trying to apply a pause but no matter what method I try (pause, threadsleep) it simply continues. and ignores all pauses in the mainblock. Is this a .NET bug?

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (maxDelay < 1)
    maxDelay = 1;
    newpause(maxDelay);
    // Pause(maxDelay * 60);
    Current = "Error:" + txt;
    LogUpdater.UpdateLog(f, "Error sending : " + txt + ".");
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
    bw.ReportProgress(1);

 }

 public void newpause(int maxDelay)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(maxDelay*1000);
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
    }
```

Comment: calling `DoEvents` is problematic, as that can cause other events to be processed, which could even make the method re-entrant. It isn't clear what you are trying to do, but frankly I would say: do not call `DoEvents`. That is a hack, and is a common cause of problems. In particular, `Timer` instances can be massive problems with `DoEvents` (but many other things too).

Comment: Unless I miss my guess, this is an attempt to limit the number of errors logged per second, so that you don't get 1000 log entries of the same error condition every second. And the `DoEvents()` is an attempt to make the application responsive. But... unfortunately, this isn't how you do it, not by a long shot. :( Marc is right - this just makes problems, and is highly likely the reason why it seems that there "is no sleep".

Comment: If you tell us your **ENTIRE** problem, we will be able to tell you the correct way of dealing with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try running following code. It works on my side.

```
 class PauseExample
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int a = 90;
            int b = 0;

            try
            {
                int c = a / b;
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.WriteLine("In catch");

                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); //waits for 5 seconds

                Console.WriteLine("Out of catch");
            }
        }
    }
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: This was the nearest to working, so have adapted something from this example. But why doesn't Pause work?

Comment: Solved with this:

System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(maxDelay *60 * 1000);

Comment: @ChrisDolan - Chris, LISTEN! We've been trying to tell you WHY it doesn't work all the time! Because the `Application.DoEvents()` calls the original method (with the try-catch) again! And if you continue doing this, you'll pretty soon run into a StackOverflow. Literally!

Answer (score 0):

Your passing one/tenth of a second.

Your only passing 10 milliseconds, 1000 would be 1 second.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // One Second.
```

Comment: The code also calls `newpause` with *at least* `1`; that then does a loop of 60 times `Sleep(maxDelay*1000)`, which is therefore: at least a minute

Comment: Correct, but when running, once it hits the catch statement it doens't pause at all, it continues

Comment: @ChrisDolan - How do you know that it continues? Do you do a step-by-step evaluation of your code, or do you just check the log?

Comment: It continues, the log shows - its sending messages, it should pause between them either on error or when no error, and it just continues to send after an error without a pause, when no error it works ok.